# Celery check if queue is executing

Tags: python, multithreading, celery, django-celery

I have to spawn celery tasks, which have to have some namespace (for example user id).
So I'm spawn it by

```
scrapper_start.apply_async((request.user.id,), queue=account.Account_username)
app.control.add_consumer(account.Account_username, reply=True)
```

And tasks spawns recursively, from other task.
Now I have to check, if tasks of queue are executing. Tried to check list length in redis, it return true number before celery start executing.
How to solve this problem. I need only to check, if queue or consumer is executing or already empty. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want to inspect the queue, you do this from command line itself.

```
 from celery.task.control import inspect
 i = inspect('scrapper_start')
 i.active()  #  get a list of active tasks
```

In addition to checking which are currently executing, you can also do the following.

```
 i.registered() # get a list of tasks registered
 i.scheduled # get a list of tasks waiting
 i.reserved() #tasks that has been received, but waiting to be executed
```

This command line inspection is good if you want to check once in a while.

For some reason, if you want to monitor them continuously, you can use [Flower](https://github.com/mher/flower) which provides a beautiful interface to monitor workers.
[image]

Comment: Not worked for me, `i = inspect('my_queue')` and then `i.ping()` gives me `ValueError: destination must be a list/tuple not <class 'str'>` this error @ChillarAnand

Comment: Try: `inspect(['my_queue'])`, with a `list` instead of a `str`, should work!